# DetailViewController Not Updating For Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitview` controller (with a master and detail view). So, when the `detailview` loads the `viewDidLoad` calls a function named `[self animateToPosition];` with the following code:

```
-(void*)animateToPosition
{
    NSLog(@"Called Function");
    [worldV animateToPosition:MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(-122.4192, 37.7793) time:1.0];

    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

    return 0;
}
```

Now, when this is first run, my `globeViewC` correctly animates to the position passed in (`worldV` is initialized and created an all in viewDidLoad of `detailviewController` also "Called Function" is printed in the log.
However, I have a view controller and in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I have the following code (in the file `masterViewController.m`)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[testArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Menu1"]) {
        DetailViewController *test=[[DetailViewController alloc]init];
        [self addChildViewController:test];
        [self.view addSubview:test.view];
        [test didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [test animateToPosition];
    }
}
```

When I select the cell called `menu1`, "Called function" DOES display in the `NSLog`, but the animation that occurred when the view was first loaded doesn't anymore. I'm wondering if I must somehow reload the `detailviewcontroller` or initialize it again (but I tried initializing it again and that didn't work)

Would like if someone could see this and help me get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could show more, especially how you `alloc` and `init` your `worldV` and what you have in your `viewDidLoad`.

Normally you don't create a new DetailViewController for SplitView setup.

Instead of creating a new DetailViewController, try to grab a hold of the existing detail view controller by creating a property:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
```

and:

```
self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
```

First thing to test here is whether your `worldV` is `nil`. A simple NSLog in `animateToPosition` would reveal the answer.

And whenever you need to call that method, do:

```
[self.detailViewController animateToPosition];
```

To animate from one coordinate to another with time, you may need to change your `animateToPosition` method to:

```
-(void)animateToPosition:(MaplyCoordinate)coordinates time:(CGFloat)time
```

Consult whether or not your `MaplyCoordinate` is an object, which I doubt.

So, to sum up, in your tableview's `viewDidLoad`, get a hold of the detail view controller.

When `didSelectRow` gets called, use the new method suggested and pass the coordinate and time this way:

```
[self.detailViewController animateToPosition:coordinates time:1.0];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Whoa, it works. Thank you. Im aware of passing the coords but i ddint get to that part of coding was just wondering why my animation was not working. was i accessing the detailviewcontroller wrong? if so...why did the nslog i have in animateToPosition run

Answer (score 0):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath function you create an DetailViewController but you don't add it to the view hierarchy. You should add it to the parent view controller like this

```
[self addChildViewController:viewController];
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

or just add it to navigation or present it as a modalViewController

Comment: hi, and thanks for the reply. i added what you suggested(please look at orginal question) however when i click the button the animation still doesnt occur, however now when i click button on my tableview, the contents of the detailview gets loaded into the table view. Seconly im not sure i want to use a navigation as i want to remain on the same screen just animate the picture